# How to modify icons in JQM 1.4.2

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to change the border color of the icons in JQM here is my code

**Image**
[image]

```
<div  data-shadow="false" data-theme="c" id="transitionmap"  data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" style="background:#006699 !important;color:#fff;">
<a data-rel="back" href="#pageone"  class="ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="location" data-iconpos="notext"  data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="d" title="Close">Go to Page One</a>
<h1><?php echo $translate->text('Ubicación Aproximada')?> </h1>
<a data-rel="back"  href="#pageone"  class="ui-nodisc-icon" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext"  data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="d" title="Close">Back</a> 
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: try to override the border attribute of the ui-icon class

Comment: I could not find the related class man . Can you please help me on this

Comment: got it man I added a new class to each button .ui-btn-my { /*with all the attribute*/ }

Comment: border color or background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to override `background-color` or `border-color` with `!important` to force override.

```
.ui-header .ui-btn { /* or use a different selector */
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border-color: #000 !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wNkVj/)**

Comment: What i did was created a new class with same structure and added that class to where ever I wanted to add change the borde/background-color of the icons it worked and off course with !important which overrides the default color . I am taking this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed tricky. Part of the issue is the new icons in 1.42 are svgs with certain colors. I suggest opening up your app in chrome so you can inspect the inheritence of all the classes not just ui-icon. I believe you have to target a series of classes to get this looking just right.

Comment: Yes actually you are right I added the css but the icons are not look like it was before . :(